# Spring security blocks outcomming requests. Connection timed out

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use Spring security in my applciation and I see that Spring Security blocks some outgoing requests

My spring config looks like this:

```
    @Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

}
```

I see that my request to rest service responde with

```
 I/O error on POST request for "https://someserver.com/api/v1/public/createUser": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

When I try to call this rest services without Spring Security(Spring security is disabled) it works fine.

Here is my config if RestTemplate

```
 public CustomRestTemplateContructor() {
        super();
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        this.restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new 
        StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }
```

Class where I do have my custom RestTemplate implementation looks like this:

```
@Configurable
public abstract class CustomRestTemplateContructor extends TestDataBase implements Runnable  {


    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRestTemplateContructor.class);

    private String testEnviroment;

    @Autowired
    private ITestDataService iTestDataService;

    private static final Object lockForAddingValueToSharedStorage = new Object();

    private String name;
    private String profileId;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;


    protected ThreadLocal<WorkerExecutionStatusThreadLocal> workerExecutionStatus = new ThreadLocal<>();



    public CustomRestTemplateContructor() {
        super();
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        this.restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }


    public ITestDataService getiTestDataService() {return iTestDataService; }
    public void setiTestDataService(ITestDataService iTestDataService) { this.iTestDataService = iTestDataService; }

    public String getTestEnviroment() { return testEnviroment; }
    public void setTestEnviroment(String testEnviroment) { this.testEnviroment = testEnviroment; }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }
    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() { return restTemplate; }
```

Then I extend my CustomRestTemplateContructor to get functionality of Spring RestTemplate and other extra functionality.

Comment: How do you use your RestTemplate? Is it a bean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. So, I don't use RestTempalate as a Spring been.
I do have class  _CustomRestTemplateContructor_ annotated  with @Configurable where I define constructor to initialize my RestTemplate and do have _getRestTemplate()_ method to use\get my implementation of RestTemplate in other classes.
Than I extend my _CustomRestTemplateContructor_ in other classes to use\get functionality of  my RestTemplate. I will update question body for you.